# How to destroy widgets in tikinter while using functions

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, error-handling

I am not able to destroy widgets in tkinter while using function

```
def first():
    photo1 = PhotoImage(file =r"file/start.png")
    photoimage1 = photo1.subsample(5,5)
    start=Button(root,
                 width=270,
                 text="LAUNCH",
                 font=("orbitron",25),
                 image=photoimage1,
                 compound="left",
                 bg="white",
                 activebackground="white",
                 command=lambda:launch(1))
def des(var):
    start.destroy()
```

It shows the following error

```
NameError: name 'start' is not defined
```

Can anyone tell the solution to this error

Comment: `start` is a local variable.

Comment: so how can I make it global

Comment: say `global start` in your `first()` function on top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can destroy by using `def des(var)` under `def(first)`